# Conditional formatting based on value of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a bunch of information that I am trying to highlight based on the value of the information in the cell to the right of the current cell. I want it to be highlighted green if the value is greater than the value to the right, and red if lesser than the value to the right.

I have so far been unsuccessful. I tried a recommendation from another post that said "=A1<B1" to highlight green and vice versa, but sadly, that did not work. A screenshot of what that did can be seen here: [image: Highlighted data based on =A1<B1 and vice versa]

Locking my columns gives me this result: [image: Locked columns]

Another attempt:
[image: Attempt with formulas]

Response to @Cyril:
[image: Response to @Cyril]

I hope you are able to help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What range did you apply that formula to? I'd expect it to have worked if you selected a range starting with A1.

Comment: Well the column of my data starts in the E column, so I did =$E1<$F1 and vice versa and then apply it to the $E$XX:$H$XX range

Comment: I don't know if it fails because it isn't in the A column? I also tried with =$A1<$B1 and same issue

Comment: @JacobK I only just now realized we all made the same typographical mistake.  I caught this when commenting to Prema's post, as I saw the rows/columns compared.  Your single-formula that doesn't work compares `E1>F1`, and the affected range is `E2:H287`... If you make that comparison, the final column gets wonky, which is expected because you are checking if a number > 0 (nothing in cell).  I will make an edit to my post to accoutn for this, which means you **can** use a single formula, with the correct references/formulae.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using conditional formatting, you need to be very careful about what gets fixed.

This formula, from your post, will affect the entire ranged acted upon:

```
"=A1<B1"
```

If you want to affect an entire row, then you need to lock the column in your formula, allowing the row number to be dynamic, e.g.:

```
"=$A1<$B1"
```

[image]

Locking a row number does not affect the range the same name, due to the comparison still being cell to cell, only the result is output over an entire range, e.g.:

[image]

If you want to have a cell:cell comparison over multiple columns, you will need to have multiple conditional formatting:

[image]

---

**Edit**:

Turns out we were all making the same typographical issue in our responses.

A single formula can work where we use the correct range references:

[image]

Note that in the above pictures, we had affected `Column A`, meaning that the carried-forward formula for conditional formatting was:

```
'For column A:
=A1>B1
'For column B
=B1>C1
```

So the last column is comparing a number versus nothing (0), which is why it kept showing up as all "green".

This was noticed when looking at Prema's post, and the "Another attempt" in Jacob's post, which had me redo the overall.  Note that we corrected in the comments section the formula and affected range being the same, where a formula for `=A1>B1` affecting `$A$2:$B$4` will show an undesired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I did try to lock my columns - I added a second photo to the question showing the result of locking my columns, and the issue seems to persist...

Comment: @JacobK sorry, i got held up in trying to get my post completed, taking over the 5 minutes to be the "edited" designation.  Please see my post, now.

Comment: @JacobK this will result in a red/green for each cell... which you can also circumvent by defaulting the interior to one of your preferred colors and using conditional formatting to change to the other color resulting in one formula per column.

Comment: Thank you @Cyril, I'll try out making additional formulas for each column, but it is still looking like it is misunderstanding what numbers I'm comparing

Comment: @Cyril first I was thinking like your last example, but I tried and it works with only one rule, see my answer

Comment: @Cyril, thank you for your help - I uploaded a new photo to the post showing what happens when I create several formulas... it still isn't consistent :(

Comment: @JacobK If you are making formulae for conditional formatting of each column, you can clearly indicate what is to be compared.  When it comes to the "single formula" of `A1>B1` spread over multiple columns, I have the same issue you have, which is why I've always done the multiple columns.

Comment: Yearh that's what I thought but it is still not consistent in the output of the highlights when I do multiple formulas?

Comment: @JacobK look at your ranges in your update.  comparing rows 1 and affecting range 2.

Comment: Oh wow, I just only realized, that was it... Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JacobK if this resolved your issue, please mark as answered.

Comment: @Prema I made an edit because you made me catch an error I made when I responded to your, now-deleted post.

Comment: @Cyril you need to color the first column also. But maybe not the last column, if JakobK doesn't want. He didn't write that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can realise it with just one formula: in my opinion you need one formula for the green colour and one for the red colour. I've done it in the following way: (according to the Chinese, a drawing says more than a thousand words :-) )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this
The formula without locking but different columns
=E1<F1
=E1>F1

[image]

Comment: Hmm I see that this solution works for you, and I am trying to do the same thing, however it isn't working for me... I'll add another photo to the post

Comment: @JacobK add picture of the rule manager as well, so we see your formulas.

Comment: I uploaded two attempts with the rule manager, I apologize for the danish but I hope you get the most important details!

Comment: @Prema Notice how 10:40 and 2:3 are compared and the output in column H; that is the issue with single-formula conditional formatting over multiple columns

Comment: @cyril I thought a lot about this. Finaly I came up with that this solution is correct. If one doesn't want the last column green one can change the refrence so only column E to H will get the color.